# What is the responsibility of sql engine, analysis engine, report db and report server in PBRS?

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

PBRS components: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/capacity-planning

1. Power bi report server
2. Sql engine
3. Analysis engine
4. Report server db

1 sits on serverA. 2, 3 sit on SQL serverB. 4 sits on SQL serverC.

What is the role of each of the above?

Answer (score 1):

In the [MS Capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/capacity-planning) planning diagram, the four items you have mentioned in your question are:

1 - Hosts the instance of Power BI Report Server, but only the front end of the application. All objects and metadata is stored in 4 (See below)

2 & 3 - Is a server hosting an instance of SQL Server and Analysis Services, these will be data sources for the reports that you have created.

4 - Is a server an instance of SQL Server to host the back end database of Power BI Report Server. This Report Server catalog holds all the reports, meta data and other objects for the frontend. It is set up during installation of PBIRS

This is not any sort of best practice, just a diagram of the topology, for example, I would not have an instance of the SQL Server DB engine and SSAS on the same server.

Comment: Each server needs sql server license?

Comment: just 2 and 4, the PBIRS just needs MS Server. It very rare to have the SSRS/PBIRS on its own dedicated SQL Server, but it will depend on the load.

Comment: In case of import mode, where pbrs fetches data from source dbs and spins up its own analysis engine, I believe this is the kind of load that requires the pbrs to have its own server?

Comment: Yes, PBIRS spins up it own hidden Analysis services instance, so you have to make sure that the server PBIRS is hosted on will have enough memory to hold multiple reports in memory (15 to 25GB spare after OS and other stuff is normally good), and I would recommend a dedicated server to host PBIRS as not to impact other apps running on it.